# Validate xmi model using OCL in Java

Tags: java, eclipse-emf, xmi, ocl, ecore

I am trying to create a stand alone Java application that accepts an xmi model and an OCL file containing constraints applied to the model's meta-model. The application then validates the model against the ocl.

I have managed to do this inside eclipse using the EMF. However when I start to create the java app, many libraries are missing. Some of which I was able to locate in the plugins directory but some seem to be missing.

For example

```
org.eclipse.ocl.examples.library.oclstdlib.OCLstdlib;
```

cannot be found.

Is there a straight forward way, using the EMF to accomplish what I am trying to do. I have been trying to create something very much like the following:

http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/da_sw_tf/trunk/OCL/src/ocl/OCLEvaluator.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eclipse plugins were located in my personal folder under .eclipse. I had completely forgotten about the personal instances of the plugins. Instead I re-installed everything only to realise the the libraries were not in the install directory plugins folder.

Installing the EMF and OCL plugins from the following link were correct.

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler

note: you may have to change the above url to suit your particular eclipse version.

Answer (score 2):

Something missing, usually means something bad configured. Without more information I can only point you out to the [OCL Help](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.ocl.doc/help/PivotStandalone.html?cp=38_6_2), where it explains why and how you need to do some manual registrations in order to execute OCL code in standalone mode.

Taken from the help:

> "If you use Eclipse OCL within Eclipse you should find that the
>   appropriate registrations are provided for you automatically by the
>   plugin registration mechanisms.
>
> However if you use Eclipse OCL outside Eclipse, for instance in JUnit
>   tests, you must provide the corresponding registrations in your code."

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read that help page many times. I appreciate the help though, considering my post is very broad.